# ScrollTop doesn't scroll to the bottom when data rendered is much - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a web application where I have custom console log, where I display all the messages, and whatever happens within the app using sockets. Every time, a socket event occurs, it appends an `li` element to the list and scroll the container to the very bottom to show the new message at the log.

But, when the rendered data becomes a lot, then the scrollbar doesn't go to the very bottom, but just stays on the same place. Just for few number of hit it scrolls to the bottom.

**Below is my code: -**

```js
socket.on("consoleData", function(data) {
  $(".log-container ul").append("<li><b>" + data.a + "<b> : " + data.m + "</li>");
  $('.log-container').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.log-container').height()
  }, 500);

});
```

As you can see, when the console data become a bit larger, then the scrollbar doesn't move .
[image]

Comment: Got a question, or just a tale of woe? What about setting `display: none` to elements that are scrolled out of view, combined with faking the scroll-bar. That should stay nice and fast.

Comment: So, you want me to hide the rest of elements which are out of view ? @enhzflep

Comment: It was merely a suggestion. That's how ListView elements are often implemented. With less data to display (or hidden surfaces to remove), the browser will have a far more pleasant time keeping your view in-sync with the data you're blasting at it.

Comment: On top of what @enhzflep said, you should close your `<b>` element - as it is now, you're just opening two `<b>` elements and not closing them. Also, depending on how frequent your log is, jQuery's animate might not be the best solution - use jQuery's `scrollTop()` instead of animate.

Comment: @darshanags - missed the unclosed `<b>`'s - wouldn't surprise me if that fixes the problem, no need for the hidden element hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem with this code is, I have taken the height of the parent element i.e; `$('.log-container').height()` which is equal to `328px`. And on the other hand I am appending the `li` elements to the `ul`, not the `div.log-container` itself. Which only increases the height of the `ul`, and its parent scroll those elements. When I find out the height of the `ul` it was `6000+px`, and the element was only scrolling upto `328px`.

So now both of them works for me :

```js
//Method One, using Animate property.

$(".log-container").animate({

  scrollTop: $(".log-container ul").height()

}, 800);



//Method Two, using scrollTop()

$(".log-container").scrollTop($(".log-container ul").height());
```